# get current location in Galaxy Tab

Tags: android, geolocation, gps, latitude-longitude, galaxy-tab

I have galaxy Tab and I want to get current lat long from my code. That code working properly in android Emulator after sending lat long from DDMS. But when I integrate this code in my galaxy Tab I cant get current lat and long... So any one have solution for device than please help me...

Comment: @Paul it has since been deleted. It was the same question by the same user, I'm deleting the link.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings -> Location & Security Settings -> USE GPS

this should help

Comment: thanx rohit, but  GPS service is already Enable . and i m able to get current lat long using default application of Galaxy Tab .

Comment: humm then try this. Settings -> Application Settings -> Development -> Allow mock location

Comment: ok.thanx .i m trying this ..but i dont konw what it mock location ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing general settings of Galaxy Tab , where you might be able to check an option on how to get your current location like , using 3G or wifi.

Comment: thanx , but  GPS service is already Enable . and i m able to get current lat long using default application of Galaxy Tab .

Answer (score 0):

[Turn on GPS.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843675/how-do-i-find-out-if-the-gps-of-an-android-device-is-enabled/843716#843716)

edit : 
My guess is that OP's device gps daemon was not able to get a position fix.

- Maybe s/he had no working data connection
- Or s/he was indoors
- Or gpsd had some error (which may have been solved by a reboot)

Comment: thanx Reno , but  GPS service is already Enable . and i m able to get current lat long using default application of Galaxy Tab .

Comment: Can you see the GPS icon on the top ? Is it animating ? If it's still you should have no problem.

Comment: Then wait for it to get a position fix. It take 2-10 minutes. It should stop animating once a fix is obtained.

Comment: Youre welcome. You can mark the green tick mark beside if this answer helped you.

Comment: Link rot may be true for external links. This was a long time ago, updated the answer. ta