# How to determine my current location (longitude,latitude and altitude)?

Tags: android, geolocation, gps, android-location

I want to determine my curent position (latitude, longitude and altitude).
In my database, I have a table contents by table location (id,name,address,longitude,latitude,altitude)

How can I determine my curent position and the most near location?

I Added this in manifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

How can i use the methods (.getlongitude(); .getLatitude(); .getaltitude()

In [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html) this is not clear.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First Enable Ur GPS.

```
    private static final long MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1; // in Meters
    private static final long MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES = 1000; // in Milliseconds

    public static double lontitube,latitude;

    protected LocationManager locationManager;
    protected Location currentLocation;
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 
                MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES, 
                MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,
                new MyLocationListener()
        );
}

 protected void performReverseGeocodingInBackground() {
        showCurrentLocation();

    }

    protected void showCurrentLocation() {

        currentLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        if (currentLocation != null) {
            String message = String.format(
                    "Current Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s",
                    currentLocation.getLongitude(), currentLocation.getLatitude()

            );
            lontitube=currentLocation.getLongitude();
            latitude=currentLocation.getLatitude();

            System.out.println("----lati----longi----"+latitude+"\n"+lontitube);

               Toast.makeText(Demo.this, message,
               Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }   

    private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

       String message = String.format(
                    "New Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s",
                    location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude()
            );
            Toast.makeText(Demo.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle b) {
            Toast.makeText(Demo.this, "Provider status changed",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
            Toast.makeText(Demo.this,
                    "Provider disabled by the user. GPS turned off",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
            Toast.makeText(Demo.this,
                    "Provider enabled by the user. GPS turned on",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
```

In AndroidManifest add

> ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

permission for GPS use.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Answer (score 4):

You can choose to either get the last known location, or listen for updates.  The easiest way is to get the latest:

Location lastKnownLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

If you want an accurate location, you need to listen forupdates using requestLocationUpdates().

Also, remember to check whether the GPS device is enabled, see [How do I find out if the GPS of an Android device is enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843675/how-do-i-find-out-if-the-gps-of-an-android-device-is-enabled)

To find the nearest addresses, see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html