# How to check status of GPS in device with android OS?

Tags: android, gps

I have made an android applicaiton (2.2) with GPS functionality.But I want to check GPS status in device is it turn on or turn off.
But don't know how to check by programming.
Please give me some advice for this question.

Thanks in advance.
Edit:

Here is the code for location listener

```
 lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        ll = new mylocationlistener();
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, ll);
        lm.addGpsStatusListener(this);


private class mylocationlistener implements LocationListener {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            mLastLocationMillis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
            mLastLocation = location;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find all the answers here: [How can I check the current status of the GPS receiver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021176/android-gps-status) and here: [How do I find out if the GPS of an Android device is enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843675/how-do-i-find-out-if-the-gps-of-an-android-device-is-enabled)

Comment: what is a fix? in the answer that is mentioned on your link ,the guy is talking about a fix on the gps.. what does that mean?

Comment: A GPS position fix is a valid GPS position returned by a device. (more at [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fix_%28position%29))

Comment: is a any permissions to be added to the android.manifest file?

Comment: yes. As stated in link in my answer you should add ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION to the manifest (more at [android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION))

Comment: did that already when i implemented the onLocationChanged method.

Comment: the method that is suggested in the link that you gave does not work. i have tried it. GPS status changed is never called. i am sitting in a building if that would make any difference.

Comment: Are you using emulator? If so you will have to provide GPS fix yourself. To do this you need to do the following: 1. connect to emulator by invoking _telnet localhost 5554_ 2. send location data to it by providing latitude and longitude _geo fix -121.45356 46.51119 4392_ as described here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279647/how-to-emulate-gps-location-in-the-android-emulator/5632107#5632107](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279647/how-to-emulate-gps-location-in-the-android-emulator/5632107#5632107)

Comment: no i am using a device. Also the method , onlocationchanged is not being called? the gpsstatuschanged is being called, but not locationchanged? what could be going wrong? i have add code for requestlocationupdates().

Comment: You could provide the code of your implementation. Is app working fine od emulator? Especially if you provide fix from console? Remember that it could take up to couple minutes to get a fix (it depends on sky visibility). Have you tested other apps using gps position on your device?

Comment: yes, there is the most common, google maps. it works fine on device.Also i have not tested the app on emulator with fixed co-ordinates, what could be going wrong, why is onlocationchanged not being called?

Answer (score 0):

1) Call `addGpsStatusListener()` add your listener to it.

2) In the `onGpsStatusChanged()` callback call the function getGpsStatus()

OR

If you are interested in Sattelite info. you can get it in the LocationListener when requesting for GPS location [onStatusChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html#onStatusChanged%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle%29)