# How to toggle GPS from an Android appwidget?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Enable GPS programatically like Tasker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721449/enable-gps-programatically-like-tasker)

I am making an app that shows gps icon as widget on home-screen. Now, i want to toggle GPS on or off when clicking this icon. I am stuck here. Any help?

Comment: See this thread, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721449/enable-gps-programatically-like-tasker

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 1):

You cannnot turn on/off GPS in android, see
[How can I enable or disable the GPS programmatically on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721449/enable-gps-programatically-like-tasker)
or
[Is there way to programmatically enable GPS on Android 2.1 & above?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211025/is-there-way-to-programmatically-enable-gps-on-android-2-1-above)

Summary is that you have to use a security hole or that you have to be a system application (application has to come within the system image). For standard apps  it is not possible.