# Android - Is there a way to listen if GPS was enabled or disabled

Tags: android, gps

I write this code to receive location updates -

```
PendingIntent launchIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 5000, intent, 0);
manager.requestLocationUpdates(selectProvider(), 0, 0, launchIntent);
```

I select the gps provider if its available, otherwise the network provider. Is there a way I could switch back to the gps one if it gets enabled later?

Does the system broadcast an intent when gps provider is enabled or disabled? Could I set up a listener for the same?

Comment: Not an android dev, but I know it's possible - the wifi monitor app I use (wifi manager by kostya vasilyev) can detect when wifi's enabled and updates its widget in sync with the wifi on/off status. Various GPS apps also can detect gps being enabled/disabled as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find out if the GPS of an Android device is enabled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/843675/how-do-i-find-out-if-the-gps-of-an-android-device-is-enabled)

Comment: not duplicate - other question looks for a one time check (and activate which is no longer possible), this question wants to listen for a status change

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Enabled new provider " + provider,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "GPS disconnected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG);


    Toast.makeText(this, "Please Switch on GPS." + provider,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Unclear anser.
What is this code? Is it implementation of some interface (what interface)?  How do one should use it (e.g where should one pass it)?

Comment: I agree with @luten, it is not clear what are you answering

Comment: Guys, this was answered back in 2011, there must be many new and efficient ways handle such kind of situations.

Comment: For those are still clueless about the interface, it is referring to [LocationListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener)

Answer (score 7):

You can detect if GPS status changed, e.g. if a GPS satellite fix was acquired.

Look at [`GpsStatus.Listener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/GpsStatus.Listener.html). Register it with `locationManager.addGpsStatusListener(gpsStatusListener)`.

Comment: This one is deprecated now and [GnssStatus](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/GnssStatus.Callback) should be used instead

Comment: @WahibUlHaq Can you provide example how to use `GnssStatus`? because I havent find any best practice about how to listen to gps status enable/disable