# how to call a method when the GPS is enable

Tags: android, android-location

i want to call a method when the status of GPS become enabled. i have wrote this, but it doesn't work.

```
private LocationManager locManager;
private GpsStatus mStatus;

locManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locManager.addGpsStatusListener(this);

@Override
public void onGpsStatusChanged(int event) 
{
    mStatus = locManager.getGpsStatus(null);
    switch (event) {
        case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STARTED:
            myMethod1();
            break;

        case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STOPPED:
            myMethod2();
            break;

        case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX:
            break;

        case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS:
            break;
    }
}
```

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

            // GPS Enable
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }
```

Comment: I need to know when the GPS goes from disabled to enabled

Answer (score 0):

You can detect status of GPS by following way.

Look at [GpsStatus.Listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/GpsStatus.Listener.html). Register it with locationManager.addGpsStatusListener(gpsStatusListener).

Also check this SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13524164/how-to-get-notified-when-the-gps-in-disabled-by-the-user-in-android) for better understanding.

Comment: thanks you very much for your answer, i have edit the question using you reply. The idea is intresting but i can't works it