# Custom view onMeasure(...) width and height are 0 when AlertDialog is shown

Tags: java, android, view, bitmap, android-alertdialog

My application consists of a `MapActivity`, which loads an XML view (map_layout), containing a `MapView` and a `CustomView` which extends `ImageView`.
I use the following code to setup my `MapActivity`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map_layout);
    initialise();
}
```

Then in initialise, I retrieve the `MapView` and `CustomView` from the XML file using `findViewById(...)` as usual. 
Within the `onMeasure(...)` function of my `CustomView` I use `this.getWidth()` and `this.getHeight()` to get its dimensions, which returns the correct results.

Then within my `initialise()` code I decided to check if GPS is enabled (using code similar to the first answer here: [How do I find out if the GPS of an Android device is enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843675/how-do-i-find-out-if-the-gps-of-an-android-device-is-enabled)), showing an `AlertDialog` if GPS is disabled.

The problem is now that the `onMeasure(...)` function of my `CustomView` no longer works correctly, and `this.getWidth()` and `this.getHeight()` both return 0 if the `AlertDialog` gets displayed. 
Why is this the case?

Thanks for your help in advance, if my question is unclear I'll edit it to add the full code when I have chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I needed to get the height and width within `onLayout()` instead of `onMeasure()` for some reason.