# onLocationChanged not called on some devices

Tags: android, location-client

This is a question which has been asked numerous times but I could not find a solution that always works.

I am developing an application using the Fused location provider.
In the `onConnected()` method, I am requesting for location updates and the application logic will be initiated once a location fix is generated and `onLocationChanged()` is called. (Please refer to my code below).

**Problem** `onLocationChanged()` method is never called on some devices. I use a Samsung Tab 2 and a Samsung Galaxy Grand for testing. This code works perfectly fine on the Tab 2 but does not work on Grand. By does not work, I mean that `locationClient` gets connected but `onLocationChanged()` is never called.

Earlier, I used the location manager for getting location and in that implementation, the same problem occurred. So, I tried implementing the fused location provider but I still get the same problem.

Can anyone help me out with this issue? Is there something I am missing here?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

LocationClient locationclient;
LocationRequest lr;
Location loc1;
static String address;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     

    locationclient = new LocationClient(this,this,this);
    locationclient.connect();        

}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    lr=LocationRequest.create();
    lr.setInterval(100);
    locationclient.requestLocationUpdates(lr, this);
    Log.d("LocationClient","On Connected");
}

@Override
public void onDisconnected() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    locationclient.disconnect();

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      

    // Application Logic        

    Log.d("LocationClient","Last Known Location LC:" + loc.getLatitude() + "," + loc.getLongitude());
}
}
```

Comment: If onConnected() will not be called onConnectionFailed() should be fired. You had a look on the ConnectionResult?

Comment: onConnected() is being called and connection is established. I have checked that on both devices. Inside onConnected() I request for location updates which then does not result in calling onLocationChanged.

Comment: Did you find a fix or workaround? I'm facing the same problem

Comment: No I didnt....tried everything I could find on the internet but didn't help. I am sure though, that there is some way around it; the way which google maps use or any other google app for that matter...

Comment: Some new progress in this question @Rohit ?

Answer (score 6):

I observed same behavior on Galaxy Nexus and recognized two things causing `onLocationChanged()` to not being called. There are

1. Corresponding location source is not enabled in System Settings. For `PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY` the *GPS satellites* must be enabled, for `PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY` *Wi-Fi & mobile network location* must be enabled.
2. Even for the enabled location sources there can be no valid location information available. For instance, `PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY` source is enabled, but there is no (or not good) GPS reception (e.g. device is inside a building). Or `PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY` source is enabled, but both Wi-Fi and mobile data are switched off. In those cases location cannot be detected and `onLocationChanged()` will not be called.

To fix #1 I had to check whether required location sources are enabled even before connecting to Google Services API and if they are switched off, then I notified a user asked him/her to allow location access.

To solve #2 I decided to use `LocationRequest.setExpirationDuration()`. I set timeout at about 10 seconds, and immediately after calling `requestLocationUpdates()` I post a callback delayed by same 10 seconds. If delayed callback is called before `requestLocationUpdates()`, this means location cannot be detected due to reason #2. I do three retries and then show user an error message.

Android documentation is not great at this place, that's why I hope this helps.

Comment: could you please explain a little bit more for your #2 solution? I didn't understand it very much

Answer (score 4):

```
lr.setInterval(100);
```

with it your interval is 0,1 second so it very hard for gps chipset to detect location. Your interval should be > 1 second.(with me it is > 10)

locationRequest it should be set:

`setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)` 
because `PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY` in outdoor it doesn't  get location . Code will look like :

```
lr=LocationRequest.create();

lr.setInterval(5 * 1000);// 5s

lr.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
locationclient.requestLocationUpdates(lr, this);
```

Hope this help.

Comment: I agree. Try replacing `PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY` with `PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY` as a first step in resolving anomalous behaviour with _FusedLocationProviderClient/LocationCallback_

Comment: In my case after changing `PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY ` to  `PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY ` I was able to know whether GPS is turned on, but lost an ability to call `onLocationChanged`.

Answer (score 0):

See if you're getting a passed location by testing for if (loc == null). Even though it's the same provider, maybe one device is coming back null and bombing out, resulting in a look like it's not firing.

Comment: Checking that didnt help.

Answer (score 0):

This maybe non-sense but I have faced this problem before, someone suggested that you should create your own `LocationListener` instead of letting your `MainActivity` implements `LocationListener`. Basically this:

```
locationclient.requestLocationUpdates(lr, your_location_listener);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: No this too didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by setting both parameters, minimum distance and minimum time between updates to 0.
As per what I have tested on 2 devices, now onLocationChanged() is being called regularly after requesting for updates.

Comment: I started getting problems with this approach too. On some devices, I am unable to get a location fix.

Answer (score 0):

try to remove and reinstall "`google play services`". Install it from google market link bellow,
[google play services](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms)

Answer (score -1):

Here Check this code out...

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {
double destLat, destLong;

LocationManager locationManager;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    destLat = location.getLatitude();
    destLong = location.getLongitude();
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Comment: This example is not using the Fused Location API.