# LocationListener is never called

Tags: android, locationlistener

I have a client-server application where the client sends a "ping" and the server responds back with a "pong". On receipt of the "pong", the client sends its location updates (GPS data) to the server. On receiving the location updates, the server sends a "pong" and this goes on for a while. 
The sockets (for sending and receiving messages) are created by the client and server in separate threads. I register the LocationListener in the main thread. The problem is that, I do not get any updates from the GPS. I checked the GPS by running a separate app that displays the number of satellites seen and the time taken for the first fix. It took about 90 seconds for the first fix.

The problem I have is very similar to the ones mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9007600/onlocationchanged-callback-is-never-called) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8732565/listening-to-locationmanager-gps-provider-doesnt-fire-any-locationlistener-even). Also [here](http://osdir.com/ml/Android-Beginners/2010-02/msg00535.html).

My code is given below:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    if (!isGPSEnabled) {
        Log.i(TAG,"PING: GPS not enabled");
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG,"PING: GPS enabled");
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locListener);
        Log.i(TAG,"PING: adding GPS status listener");
        locationManager.addGpsStatusListener(PingActivity.this);
    }

/*The server and client threads are started after this.*/
```

The LocationListener is as follows:

```
LocationListener locListener = new LocationListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.i(TAG, "PING: onLocationChanged");
        Log.i(TAG, "PING: location is " + location.getLatitude() + ", " + location.getLongitude());
}
```

As you can see, there are just two log statements in the LocationListener and these two log statements are not printed at all. Is it because I have a thread constantly listening for updates and the LocationListener is never invoked? I also tried creating a separate activity for the GPS and registering that before starting the client-server threads.

These are the permissions in the manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

The message I get in LogCat is

```
duplicate add listener for uid
```

Can someone throw some light on this? Thanks.

Comment: What about the other callback methods of LocationListener? Do they get triggered?

Comment: No, none of them are triggered.

Comment: Where is "LocationListener locListener = new LocationListener()..." called?

Answer (score -1):

You getting error for the code (extract from android source)

```
 private void handleAddListener(int uid) {
     synchronized(mListeners) {
         if (mClientUids.indexOfKey(uid) >= 0) {
             // Shouldn't be here -- already have this uid.
            Log.w(TAG, "Duplicate add listener for uid " + uid);
            return;
        }   
        mClientUids.put(uid, 0);
        if (mNavigating) {
            try {
                mBatteryStats.noteStartGps(uid);
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                Log.w(TAG, "RemoteException in addListener");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`mClientUids` is declared as

```
private final SparseIntArray mClientUids = new SparseIntArray();
```

And, in your code,

```
   locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locListener);
    locationManager.addGpsStatusListener(PingActivity.this);
```

In here you are adding two different listener and that is what Android is complaining about.

Comment: I used the exact same method in my stand-alone GPS app to get the GPS signals. I did not get the "duplicate add listener" method that time. I commented out that line as per your suggestion (in the current app), but still get the same message. I also uninstalled my stand-alone GPS app, but that also did not help.

Comment: Thinking that it could be due to threads trying to register the LocationListener twice, I control access to the critical section (registering the LocListener) by adding a mutex. Still no change.

Comment: for some reason Android location system getting your appid twice. You have to stop that. And, when debugging change your accuracy to a low level that way you will know if your problem with code itself or the provider.