# Play Location Services getLastLocation returns null

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

I am trying to listen to location changes but sometimes `onLocationChanged` callback is never called and `getLastLocation` returns `null`, while Google Maps always working perfectly.

**Note**

If I reboot my device the location service will work for ~2 days only; after that neither my app nor [the SDK example](http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/LocationUpdates.zip) will work while Google Maps still working.

This is my service code:

```
public class VisitService extends Service implements
        GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, 
        LocationListener {

    private final IBinder mBinder = new VisitBinder();


    // A request to connect to Location Services
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    // Stores the current instantiation of the location client in this object
    private LocationClient mLocationClient;


    private boolean mLocationServiceConnected = false;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        initLocation();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        initLocation();
        return mBinder;
    }

    public void startVisit() {
        if (!servicesConnected()) {
            listener.onVisitStartError();
            return;
        }

        if (mLocationServiceConnected) {
            if (isAcceptableLocation(mLocationClient.getLastLocation())) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "You have arrived!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            } else {
                mVisitListener.onVisitStartError();
            }
        }    
    }

    private boolean isAcceptableLocation(Location location) {
        if (location == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Location is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }


    private void initLocation() {

        if (mLocationRequest == null) {
            // Create a new global location parameters object
            mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
            /*
             * Set the update interval
             */
            mLocationRequest
                    .setInterval(LocationUtils.UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);

            // Use high accuracy
            mLocationRequest
                    .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

            // Set the interval ceiling to one minute
            mLocationRequest
                    .setFastestInterval(LocationUtils.FAST_INTERVAL_CEILING_IN_MILLISECONDS);

        }

        if (mLocationClient == null) {
            mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
            mLocationClient.connect();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Verify that Google Play services is available before making a request.
     * 
     * @return true if Google Play services is available, otherwise false
     */
    private boolean servicesConnected() {

        // Check that Google Play services is available
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil
                .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

        // If Google Play services is available
        if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == resultCode) {
            // In debug mode, log the status
            Log.d(LocationUtils.APPTAG,
                    getString(R.string.play_services_available));

            return true;
        } else {

            return false;
        }
    }

    public class VisitBinder extends Binder {
        public VisitService getService() {
            return VisitService.this;
        }
    }


    /**
     * In response to a request to start updates, send a request to Location
     * Services
     */
    private void startPeriodicUpdates() {

        mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, this);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Location Update Requested", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    /**
     * In response to a request to stop updates, send a request to Location
     * Services
     */
    private void stopPeriodicUpdates() {
        mLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.d(LocationUtils.APPTAG, "Location Services Connection faild");


    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Log.d(LocationUtils.APPTAG, "Location Services Connected");
        mLocationServiceConnected = true;
        startPeriodicUpdates();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {
        mLocationServiceConnected = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Location has been changed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

**Android Manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Comment: From the docs: `If a location is not available, which should happen very rarely, null will be returned`. Seems you are hitting the `rarely` moment, could be due device. Have you tried to get last know location from `LocationManager` instead?

Comment: I would also request "ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" in case the fine location isn't available.

Comment: You could wait for your `onLocationChanged` callback to be called before calling your `startVisit()` method. For example, you could to it this way, couldn't you? What do you exactly mean by "I cannot receive onLocationChanged" ?

Comment: @MagicMicky mean `onLocationChanged` is never invoked by play location services.

Comment: @Robert I have tried to add ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permission, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**

It's kind of bug on old Android devices.

Apparently the location APIs have different behavior on different Android versions (LocationManager has issues on Android >= 4.1, while Play Services has issues on Android 2.3), see [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=57707).

So what I ended up with is below:

Trying to retrieve last location by play services, if failed try with LocationManager.

**Second**

I would like to thank you all for your valuable suggestions, I get the hint to use the previous workaround from AndroidHacker's post so I think he is the one who deserve the bounty.

Answer (score 9):

Firstly it is a bug. I also faced this problem.

You can try a simple workaround.

Do a request for location update before you try to get last location, i.e. Request for location updates before you try to find the last location using getLastLocation();

Just like:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria crta = new Criteria();
crta.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
crta.setAltitudeRequired(true);
crta.setBearingRequired(true);
crta.setCostAllowed(true);
crta.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW); 
String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(crta, true);
Log.d("","provider : "+provider);
// String provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER; 
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1000, 0, locationListener);
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
```

This implementation is based of LocationManager. Please opt Location Client for same.

Hope it helps!

**UPDATE**

Here you can also go for onLocationChanged() method as it will update you each time location is changed while getLastLocation() method returns best known location which might be NULL.

As per doc, GetLastLocation() method will return NULL in very rare cases. But this happens often with me too.

**NEWEST UPDATE**

Guys only one update regarding GPS :

Firstly we need to make use of `GoogleApiClient` instead `LocationClient` class.

Secondly we need to implement `GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener`

Third we need to override its `onConnected()` , `onConnectionSuspended()` and `onConnectionFailed()` method.

Rest you are good to go.

CHEERS!

Comment: By rare cases I think Google means on devices like the Samsung GT-S7562, Xiaomi redmi 2, Galaxy core prime. I went to a showroom with [Google Location sample apps in github](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location) and tested on several devices. It appears to work only on newer devices like Galaxy Note 2, Note 4, OnePlus2, Xiaomi redmi note 4g, OPX, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `getLastLocation()` for a purpose other than what it was intended.  `getLastLocation()` is used when a location aware app is 1st starting.  After two days you should have a very accurate fix.  Why haven't you followed the location aware design guides.

I'd say you need to return `START_STICKY`.  But you have coded `onStartCommand()` and `onBind()`.  You'd also need to start the service then bind to it for the `START_STICKY` to work after clients have unbound.

Don't check for GooglePlay in the service.  The service needs to be light weight check for GooglePlay in an activity before starting the service.  The lighter a service is the more chance it will stay in memory.  Run the `Service` in a separate process.

Answer (score 1):

I have developed my application based on below code you can use if you want My application name is "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.deep.profilemaper" .

Here is my code : BackgroundLocationService.java

```
public class BackgroundLocationService extends Service implements
    GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,LocationListener  {

    IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

    private LocationClient mLocationClient;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
   // Flag that indicates if a request is underway.
   private boolean mInProgress;

   private Boolean servicesAvailable = false;

public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    public BackgroundLocationService getServerInstance() {
        return BackgroundLocationService.this;
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();


    mInProgress = false;
    // Create the LocationRequest object
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    // Use high accuracy
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
    // Set the update interval to 5 seconds
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(Constants.UPDATE_INTERVAL);
    // Set the fastest update interval to 1 second
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(Constants.FASTEST_INTERVAL);

    servicesAvailable = servicesConnected();

    /*
     * Create a new location client, using the enclosing class to
     * handle callbacks.
     */
    mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);


}

private boolean servicesConnected() {

    // Check that Google Play services is available
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

    // If Google Play services is available
    if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == resultCode) {

        return true;
    } else {

        return false;
    }
}

public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    if(!servicesAvailable || mLocationClient.isConnected() || mInProgress)
        return START_STICKY;

    setUpLocationClientIfNeeded();
    if(!mLocationClient.isConnected() || !mLocationClient.isConnecting() && !mInProgress)
    {
        appendLog(DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date()) + ": Started", Constants.LOG_FILE);
        mInProgress = true;
        mLocationClient.connect();
    }

    return START_STICKY;
}

/*
 * Create a new location client, using the enclosing class to
 * handle callbacks.
 */
private void setUpLocationClientIfNeeded()
{
    if(mLocationClient == null) 
        mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
}

// Define the callback method that receives location updates
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // Report to the UI that the location was updated
    String msg = Double.toString(location.getLatitude()) + "," +
            Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
    Log.d("debug", msg);
    // Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    appendLog(msg, Constants.LOCATION_FILE);
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}

public String getTime() {
    SimpleDateFormat mDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    return mDateFormat.format(new Date());
}

public void appendLog(String text, String filename)
{       
   File logFile = new File(filename);
   if (!logFile.exists())
   {
      try
      {
         logFile.createNewFile();
      } 
      catch (IOException e)
      {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
   try
   {
      //BufferedWriter for performance, true to set append to file flag
      BufferedWriter buf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(logFile, true)); 
      buf.append(text);
      buf.newLine();
      buf.close();
   }
   catch (IOException e)
   {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    // Turn off the request flag
    mInProgress = false;
    if(servicesAvailable && mLocationClient != null) {
        mLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(this);
        // Destroy the current location client
        mLocationClient = null;
    }
    // Display the connection status
    // Toast.makeText(this, DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date()) + ": Disconnected. Please re-connect.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    appendLog(DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date()) + ": Stopped", Constants.LOG_FILE);
    super.onDestroy();  
}

/*
 * Called by Location Services when the request to connect the
 * client finishes successfully. At this point, you can
 * request the current location or start periodic updates
 */
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    // Request location updates using static settings
    mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, this);
    appendLog(DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date()) + ": Connected", Constants.LOG_FILE);

}

/*
 * Called by Location Services if the connection to the
 * location client drops because of an error.
 */
@Override
public void onDisconnected() {
    // Turn off the request flag
    mInProgress = false;
    // Destroy the current location client
    mLocationClient = null;
    // Display the connection status
    // Toast.makeText(this, DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date()) + ": Disconnected. Please re-connect.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    appendLog(DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date()) + ": Disconnected", Constants.LOG_FILE);
}

/*
 * Called by Location Services if the attempt to
 * Location Services fails.
 */
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    mInProgress = false;

    /*
     * Google Play services can resolve some errors it detects.
     * If the error has a resolution, try sending an Intent to
     * start a Google Play services activity that can resolve
     * error.
     */
    if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {

    // If no resolution is available, display an error dialog
    } else {

      }
    }

}
```

*****Constants.java*****

```
public final class Constants {

// Milliseconds per second
private static final int MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND = 1000;
// Update frequency in seconds
private static final int UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS = 30;
// Update frequency in milliseconds
public static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL = MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND * UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS;
// The fastest update frequency, in seconds
private static final int FASTEST_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS = 30;
// A fast frequency ceiling in milliseconds
public static final long FASTEST_INTERVAL = MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND * FASTEST_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS;
// Stores the lat / long pairs in a text file
public static final String LOCATION_FILE = "sdcard/location.txt";
// Stores the connect / disconnect data in a text file
public static final String LOG_FILE = "sdcard/log.txt";


/**
 * Suppress default constructor for noninstantiability
 */
private Constants() {
    throw new AssertionError();
    }
}
```

This code contains some variables like current Date and Time and constants like LOG_File that is only for logging purpose . so, i have excluded that code .
This code is perfectly tested and working . Give it a try.

Thanks.

Comment: I have used Fused Location Provider in this code so you don't have to switch between Network or GPS provider . See https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I think it's kinda bug on old android devices, +1 for nice UI:)

Answer (score 1):

This problem can appear if google maps hasn't determined location of your device yet. Try launching Google Maps. If it can not then fix this issue in device's settings (say by enabling WLAN + GPS).

Answer (score 0):

From [the doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationClient.html#getLastLocation()), it's clear that it's sometime possible that the `getLastLocation()` returns null. So, depending on what you mean by "*I cannot receive onLocationChanged callbacks*", you could just delay your `startVisit` important calls (your toast display right now) until you have received this onLocationChanged callback. This way, if you have a direct access to the last known location, this will be direct, and otherwise you wait for the onLocationChanged callbacks

```
public class VisitService extends Service implements
        GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, 
        LocationListener {
    //...
    boolean mIsInitialized=false;
    Location mCurrentLocation;
    boolean mStartVisitsCalled=false;
    //...

    public void startVisit() {
        if (!servicesConnected()) {
            listener.onVisitStartError();
            return;
        }

        if (mLocationServiceConnected) {
        if (((mLocationClient.getLastLocation() != null && isAcceptableLocation(mLocationClient.getLastLocation()))
                || (isInitialized && isAcceptableLocation(mCurrentLocation))) {
                //doNiceStuff();
            } else
                mStartVisitsCalled=true;
                //Wait...
            }
        }    
    }
    //...

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        this.mIsInitialized=true;
        this.mCurrrentLocation = location;
        if(mStartVisitsCalled) {
            //delayed doNiceStuff();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately sometimes `onLocationChange` is never called, when that happen in also the SDK example wont work.

Comment: have you tried using `requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);` and `requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);` to request location updates more precisely? (as detailed here http://stackoverflow.com/a/9008453/1376834
)

Comment: And, would you try to check in your `onConnected()` what are the value of `getLastLocation`?

Comment: Since you are using the Google Play Services,Can you enabled Wifi and connect to SSID and try again. I have faced this issue earlier, Since the fused location provider tries to find the location, in case of wifi is not present it sometimes doesn't get location changed?

Answer (score 0):

Its possible that your service is just being killed, it can happen.
Try changing the value returned from your onStartCommand() to

```
return STICKY_START;
```

This will restart the service as soon as resources are available.

Here is the relevant section in the [API Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

public static final int START_STICKY

Added in API level 5
Constant to return from onStartCommand(Intent, int, int): if this service's process is killed while it is started (after returning from onStartCommand(Intent, int, int)), then leave it in the started state but don't retain this delivered intent. Later the system will try to re-create the service. Because it is in the started state, it will guarantee to call onStartCommand(Intent, int, int) after creating the new service instance; if there are not any pending start commands to be delivered to the service, it will be called with a null intent object, so you must take care to check for this.

This mode makes sense for things that will be explicitly started and stopped to run for arbitrary periods of time, such as a service performing background music playback.

Constant Value: 1 (0x00000001)

Comment: Thanks @nPn but I don't think this is the issue because I can see some `Toasts` create by the service.

Comment: I looks like most of your toasts would be early and then you would be just keep taking periodic location updates, so are you saying you are getting ongoing toasts from the service but not seeing onLocationChanged being called?

Comment: Actually I can see `Location is null`, `Location Services Connected`, `Location Update Requested` ... but not `Location has been changed` so I'm sure that my service is running but `onLocationChanged` is not being called.

Answer (score 0):

The google maps must be working because it must be caching the previous location info or directly using location api-not the google play services location api..