# VS Xamarin android error- resource directory ..\resourcecache\637B247E1...B9\re does not exist

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, google-api, xamarin.android, google-play-services

I've been struggling with this error for the past week when I try to use Google Map in my application in visual studio 2015.

`Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       resource directory 'C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\App2\App2\obj\Debug\resourcecache\637B247E17F6C444444444D51C9757B9\res' does not exist  App2    C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\App2\App2\AAPT`.

I have followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W6Q0olRPsus&index=40&list=PLCuRg51-gw5VqYchUekCqxUS9hEZkDf6l and have done everything step by step.
This error even happened when I created new project and add "Google play services-Maps" and "Google play services-Location" components and built it.

I have done this steps too:

- Install "Google play services" using "Android Sdk manager"
- Update Xamarin to latest version
- Update android sdk
- Deleted the bin & obj directories
- Performed a "Clean" followed by a "Rebuild"

Comment: Did you try and delete your obj and bin folders?

Comment: As I mentioned yes, I deleted them

Comment: Can you look at the log file? see link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25017764/play-location-services-getlastlocation-returns-null