# Permission Denied Exception while Turning ON GPS Programmatically

Tags: android, android-permissions

I need to enable GPS programmatically so that I used following to code enable GPS:

```
            String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);

        if (!provider.contains("gps")) { // if gps is disabled
            final Intent poke = new Intent();
            poke
                    .setClassName("com.android.settings",
                            "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
            poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
            poke.setData(Uri.parse("3"));
            sendBroadcast(poke);
```

But when i Used this code I got following Exception:

```
    01-25 12:11:37.218: W/ActivityManager(477): Permission denied: checkComponentPermission() reqUid=1000
    01-25 12:11:37.218: W/ActivityManager(477): Permission Denial: broadcasting Intent { cat=[android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE] dat=3 cmp=com.android.settings/.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider } from com.gpstraking (pid=982, uid=10186) requires null due to receiver com.android.settings/com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider
```

What permission I have to give to avoid this exception and Enable GPS.

Comment: which version device you are using??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5305835/1395259

Comment: I have tested on Android 2.3 and Android 4.0.1

Comment: Yes i Used the same code but its not working

Comment: not possible. See this link  http://stackoverflow.com/a/9350691/1395259 and this  http://stackoverflow.com/a/10302940/1395259

Comment: after 2.2 its depricated to turn on the GPS programatically. The only way to ask the user to turn on the GPS

Comment: If your device rooted you can enable/disable GPS in software. Not trivial but possible.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have below line in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: If you have already done this. update the question with all the permissions added in the manifest

Comment: This is not enough. The application must be the system application. It can be done with rooted device only.

Comment: Permission is only granted to system apps;