# No GPS location updates on Galaxy S3

Tags: android, gps

I'm developing a GPS tracker and it works like a charm. But a couple of weeks ago a customer of me (a trackage company) bought Samsung Galaxy S3s for his drivers. And since that we have really strange behaviour of my app.

The app receives location updates from GPS receiver, but after some hours of work it doesn't receive any location updates.

I have registered the app for `onGpsStatusChanged()` too and in this time `onGpsStatusChanged()` was called (I see that GPS receiver have 10-17 satellites!), but the method `onLocationChanged()` was not called! After the service restart (=re-registering of `LocationListener`) it works again.
It is really strange. It seems that after some hours of work the GPS reciever is not in the mood for calling `onLocationChanged()` :)

Any idea what may be wrong?

@matekm:
The log looks like:

> onLocationChanged() <- new location
>
> onGpsStatusChanged() (GPS started / stopped / GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS etc)

...

> onLocationChanged() <- new location
>
> onGpsStatusChanged() (GPS started / stopped / GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS etc)

...

> onLocationChanged()

<<<<< - from here no location updates more and no other GPS event status except GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS!

> onGpsStatusChanged() GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS numOfSatellites=15
> onGpsStatusChanged() GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS numOfSatellites=15
> onGpsStatusChanged() GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS numOfSatellites=16
> onGpsStatusChanged() GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS numOfSatellites=15
> onGpsStatusChanged() GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS numOfSatellites=17
> onGpsStatusChanged() GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS numOfSatellites=15
> ...

Comment: what status is reported with onGpsStatusChanged? Do You have any logs from Your app?

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12159524/mylocationoverlay-not-calling-onproviderdisabled/12160404#12160404

Comment: Same here, I have an application that works on all other platforms (I tried a while pile of phones from 2.1 - 4.1). On the S3 it does not call onLocationChange. If you find a solution please let us know

Comment: At the moment I have only a "stupid" solution. But it works. I re-register my LocationListener if there were no location updates since X seconds and in this time interval onGpsStatusChanged() was called with more than Y satellites.

Answer (score 0):

I read somewhere the S3 supports [GLONASS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLONASS), and it works a tat different then the GPS system thats normally worked in the other phones, like the S2, although I believe GLONASS is a backup, or it works together. It might be that it sends wrong coordinates or coordinates in a form your application cant read. But if you say it works for 4 hours on an S3 but then fails. It doesn't happen on other phones, just on the S3. Might maybe be handy to narrow it down to see if other phones have the same problem or just the S3?

Comment: At the moment I made some tests with Nexus S and Galaxy S2 and I couldn't observe this strange behaviour on these phones. Other my customers use other phones but no one complained about such problems.