# android getlastknown location crashes in samsung galaxy s3

Tags: android, google-maps

My app crashes when I try to get my location on a samsung galaxy s3. It works perfect on 3 other phones that I have tested. I just have remote testers on the samsung galaxy s3 so I can't get the error message. Here's my code:

```
    Location finalLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
    locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);

    Location net_loc=null, gps_loc=null;
    if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
        gps_loc=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER))
        net_loc=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    //if there are both values use the latest one
    if(gps_loc!=null && net_loc!=null){
        if(gps_loc.getTime()>net_loc.getTime())
            finalLocation = gps_loc;
        else
            finalLocation = net_loc;
    }

    if(gps_loc!=null){
        finalLocation = gps_loc;

    }
    if(net_loc!=null){
        finalLocation = net_loc;

    }
```

Comment: Have them install a logcat application and get you the crash logs...

Comment: Android apps do not use the Google Maps API V3. (tag replaced)

Comment: Can you refer this post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916568/getting-null-from-getlastknownlocation-on-sdk

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a "feature" with the 4.0.4 release, check[(getLastKnownLocation does not work on Samsung Galaxy S3 4.0.4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13017219/getlastknownlocation-does-not-work-on-samsung-galaxy-s3-4-0-4?rq=1).

I had the same problem and it went away when I upgraded to 4.1.

you probably must catch the case where both are null, I found that PASSIVE_PROVIDER works.

```
   if ( gps_loc == null && net_loc == null ) { // only S3 gets this....
      finalLocation=  locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER);
   }
   if ( finalLocation == null ) panic....
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell the exact issue without a logcat, but getLastKnownLocation can return null in some cases (not likely but possible).  If that is the case here it is easy to see that would cause a crash.  Maybe try adding in some code to check that getLastKnownLocation returned a value and if not either use a dummy value or 'pause' your actions and grab the location yourself.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation(java.lang.String)