# How can i check if my android phone lost its GPS signal?

Tags: android, gps

Hi, is there a way i can check if my android phone has lost its GPS signal. I can find out if the GPS signal is retrieved back but is there a way i can check when the signal is initially lost?

I have tried checking if the longitude or latitude is 0, but i have not observed either of them becoming 0 when i lose the signal.

Thank You!!

Comment: define "lost the signal"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check out the answers to these 2 questions...

**[stackoverflow.com/questions/843675](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843675/how-do-i-find-out-if-the-gps-of-an-android-device-is-enabled)**

**[stackoverflow.com/questions/2021176](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021176/how-can-i-check-the-current-status-of-the-gps-receiver)**