# How to ask for permission like this in Android

Tags: android

Hello im noob Android developer and i want to to make something like this image. It happens when i click the auto localization in gmap

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezvP2.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do mean a dialog box like this?

It's an alert dialog. And you will find very useful information about it and implementations of it in these documentation :).

[**Android dialogs**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)

Comment: Yeah i wanted it but how can i know if the device has the gps enabled thanks and reqiesy permission to active it

Comment: Look here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/843675/how-do-i-find-out-if-the-gps-of-an-android-device-is-enabled