# Check if GPS is turned on using LocationServices, not LocationManager?

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-play-services, location-services

Is there a way to check if gps is turned off using LocationServices rather than using LocationManager?

I am using LocationServices and GoogleApiClient and trying to figure out the method that we can use to check if gps is on.

I want to solve the problem without using LocationManager, if it's possible to find the GPS source rather than having a mixed of everything which LocationServices seems to do? Please correct me if I am mistaking.

Answer (score 1):

LocationServices are Services build on top of Location, such as Fuse, Geofencing etc.. they are built on top of LocationManager

You want to check what is the status of the GPS, it can be done with LocationManager, as you do right now.

Like that:
[How do I find out if the GPS of an Android device is enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843675/how-do-i-find-out-if-the-gps-of-an-android-device-is-enabled)