# How to put GPS status in text box

Tags: android, gps

Basically, in case GPS is turned on under text box to say 'Enabled' and if it is turned of, put text in text box that says 'Disabled'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find this code i hope it will help you

```
PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
boolean hasGps = pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_LOCATION_GPS);
if(hasGps){
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){            
//set enable into TextView here         
}else{
//set Disable into TextView here 
}
}else{
//set Toast for GPS not available into your device
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
textbox_name.setText("Enable");
}
else
textbox_name.setText("Disabled");
```

Try this it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

It's nothing about Android development, it's basically simple thinking, but in Android it will look like (assuming you have the other parts):

```
textView.setText(isGpsTurnedOn ? "Enabled" : "Disabled");
```

If you're interested in getting the GPS status, then look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843675/how-do-i-find-out-if-the-gps-of-an-android-device-is-enabled) question.