# Identify distinctly if android service location and gps is enabled in background

Tags: android, gps

I have this scenario : My android service location is enabled but my gps (gps symbol) is not enabled.

[image: service location]

[image: gps]

I want to check if my service location is enabled or not and launch activity.
I want to check if my gps (see gps print screen - gps symbol) is enabled or not and toast message to user.

The code below checks if my gps (see gps print screen - gps symbol) is enabled or not only **but does not check if service location is enabled.** **<== this is what I need to... thx**

```
final LocationManager locationManager =
            (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    try {
        gps_enabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

I need to identify both situations and handle this...

Lets suppose I have my gps (background) disabled. (see gps print screen - gps symbol)
and 
I have my service location enabled.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/843675/how-do-i-find-out-if-the-gps-of-an-android-device-is-enabled/7990939#7990939

Comment: thats the deal. I checked gps disabled with the locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER how can I know if my service location is enabled or not ...

Comment: Looks like you have only the network provider enabled.  You can check that too using the same way you check the GPS provider.

Comment: nop. In this situation as you can see in print screen I have service location enabled and gps (gps_provider) disabled.

Comment: After @drschultz reply I got what you told in comment thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [`LocationManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) to determine which location services are available, you'll be able to tell if location services are turned on or off. For instance, with the following code:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
boolean isGpsEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
boolean isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

Log.d("LOCATION SERVICES", "isGpsEnabled="+isGpsEnabled+" isNetworkEnabled="+isNetworkEnabled);
```

If the device Location Services are turned off, both `isGpsEnabled` and `isNetworkEnabled` will be false. If just GPS is turned off, but location services are turned on, `isGpsEnabled` would be false, but `isNetworkEnabled` would be true. If the device has location services turned on, including GPS, then both will be true.