# How to know in android if location is turned off by user

Tags: android, location

How can I identify that if the location turned off by the user in android? 
I also want to show a dialog to go to settings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public static boolean canGetLocation() {
    return isLocationEnabled(App.appInstance); // application context
}

public static boolean isLocationEnabled(Context context) {
    int locationMode = 0;
    String locationProviders;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        try {
            locationMode = Settings.Secure.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE);
        } catch (Settings.SettingNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return locationMode != Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_OFF;
    } else {
        locationProviders = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE);
        return !TextUtils.isEmpty(locationProviders);
    }
}
```

This is a quick tool to check if device location is enabled or not, Hope this helps.

This will return a boolean indicating enabled or not.

And you can navigate not location settings by using the following intent from the alert dialog click listener,

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
```

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm!

Comment: Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE is now deprecated. Any alternative solution?

Comment: @nandu Which Sdk version are you targeting ?

Comment: @Sanoop version 28

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger a broadcast receiver to know the gps is turned on/ off.

answer is here : [How to trigger broadcast receiver when gps is turn on/off?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20673620/how-to-trigger-broadcast-receiver-when-gps-is-turn-on-off)

to check if gps is on or off : [How to check if GPS is Disabled Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34184903/how-to-check-if-gps-is-disabled-android)