# Why check of GPS_PROVIDER isProviderEnabled is always "false"?

Tags: android, gps

I can't determinate is GPS Turned ON or OFF, isProviderEnabled is always "false" but GPS is Turned ON.

```
public abstract class BaseGPSActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

  @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Log.v(TAG, " GPS is enabled: "+isGPSEnabled()))
```

---

```
 public boolean isGPSEnabled(){
        String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
        if(provider != null)
            Log.v(TAG, " Location providers: "+provider);
        return mLocationManager!=null && mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER );
    }
```

Output is :

```
V/BaseGPSActivity:  Location providers: network

V/BaseGPSActivity:  GPS is enabled:  false
```

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/7990939/5305430

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**That was because need to check "High accuracy" in Settings of the device. That GPS Provider will be enabled.**
[image]