# How to check if GPS is enabled on device in Flutter?

Tags: android, google-maps, flutter

How can I check if the GPS feature is enabled on a device, so that I can update a map widget. I've already done the location permission handler feature part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am having issues duplicating this question.

As per this **[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843675/how-do-i-find-out-if-the-gps-of-an-android-device-is-enabled)**, the best way is

```
 final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService( Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );

    if ( !manager.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ) ) {
        buildAlertMessageNoGps();
    }

  private void buildAlertMessageNoGps() {
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Your GPS seems to be disabled, do you want to enable it?")
           .setCancelable(false)
           .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(@SuppressWarnings("unused") final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
                   startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
               }
           });
    final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I needed

Answer (score -2):

add [geolocator](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator)  package to your project , then you can check if location is enabled or not with :

```dart
  final Geolocator _geolocator = Geolocator();
  ...
  ...
 bool enabled = await _geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
```